# Python:Normalized histogram with bin definition

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

```
def histg(x,bins):
n, bins = plt.hist(x, bins,normed=True)
plt.show()
return (plt)
```

I want to create bins by dividing the min and max of the data in to equal intervals. 
Considering a sample data

---

**X** :
67
45
22
48
91
46
52
61
58.

---

How do i do it in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = [67, 45, 22, 48, 91, 46, 52, 61, 58]
bins = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 10)
def histg(x,bins):
    n = plt.hist(x, bins,normed=True)
    plt.show()
    return n

histg(x, bins) # Store in some variable in case you want to further process
```